# is CBT used for snapshots?

Tags: vmware-esx, snapshot

1) Just wondering, is Change Block Tracking utilised for snapshots (ESX 4.x)? or is the mechanism the same as ESX 3.x

2) I know its used for SVM after reading a punching clouds article (http://www.punchingclouds.com/?p=896). However in ESX 3.x the VMDK needed to be RO before you could copy data out of it, so I gather that CBT enables you to read a RW VMDK?

3) Because of the quiecing cycle to enable CBT does this need to be done before a VM can be SVM'd?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes it'll be used by snapshots if it's enabled - but you'll have to manually enable CBT on a vmdk-to-vmdk basis as it's not enabled by default.
2. Don't understand your question, can you rewrite it to be clearer please.
3. No, SVM will sort this for you as it's CBT-aware.